# Bundle size is big, how to reduce size of app.js?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, laravel-mix

I am using Vue.js and have only 4 components in my project.

I imported only `bootstrap`, `jquery` and `lodash`:

```
import { map } from 'lodash';
import 'bootstrap/js/dist/modal';
import $ from "jquery";
```

But `npm run production` creates
bundle of **400kb size**.

`npm run production` is configured as shown below.

```
cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js
```

#### Is it possible to reduce bundle size to ~100KB ? If yes how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## You should add [bundle analyzer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-bundle-analyzer) to your webpack config.

That tool will help you to understand what is going on with your final bundle for example:

- you have imported something accidentally and didn't noticed that
- one of your dependencies is really big and you should avoid using it
- you accidentally imported whole library when you just wanted to import single function from that library (that is common with `lodash`)

### Here is an example of how you can add bundle analyzer to your webpack config:

```
const { BundleAnalyzerPlugin } = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer');
const isBundleAnalyze = true; // turn it too true only when you want to analyze your bundle, should be false by default

module.exports = {
    // ... rest webpack config here
    plugins: [
        // ... rest webpack plugins here
        ...isBundleAnalyze ? [ new BundleAnalyzerPlugin() ] : []
    ]
};
```

### Also check your final js file.

It should be a single line of code with simple variables. Something like this: `!function(e){function t(t){for(var n,r,o=t[0],i=t[1],s=0,l=[];s<o.length;s++)` if it doesn't looks like that it means that you configured your production webpack build incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty obvious why your bundle is over 400kb, you are importing `lodash` and `jquery`, you are just missing `moment.js` (a little joke), but one thing that you can do is use only what you need.

First, if you are using Vue, or React, or any of those jQuery UI libraries you shouldn't be using jQuery unless is necessary.

Another thing that you can do is import only what you need, instead of:

```js
import { map } from 'lodash';
```

try

```js
import map from 'lodash/map';
```

or even better

```js
import map from 'lodash.map';
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.map

Lazy imports, read more [here](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/lazy-loading.html). This will allow splitting your bundle into pieces that can be called at execution time, reducing considerably your app size.

```js
const Foo = () => import('./Foo.vue')
```

There is also SSR (Server Side Rendering), which is basically generating the initial HTML code of your app at build time and rendering outputting that, to show the users that something is on the site, but you also need to understand that, this won't do much, since the browser needs to parse the Javascript code (the hydration process) in order to make the site functional.

---

If you are using React as of April 2021, the React team announced [React Server Components](https://reactjs.org/blog/2020/12/21/data-fetching-with-react-server-components.html), which seems like a big thing coming up, I supposed that many other libraries will be moving components to the server (and I hope Vue does).

> Again as of today don't use it on production.

---

Other answers mentioned the use of `webpack-bundle-analyzer`, here is a trick how to use it:

*webpack.config.js*

```js
const { BundleAnalyzerPlugin } = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer');

const analyzing = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'analyze';

module.exports = {
   plugin: [
     ...(analyzing ? [new BundleAnalyzerPlugin()] : [])
   ]
}
```

on your *package.json*

```json
{
    "scripts": {
        "analyze": "NODE_ENV=analyze webpack build"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use [CompressionWebpackPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/compression-webpack-plugin/) and try gzip